# How to evaluate columns that contain lists in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Say I have a dataframe which describes the dimensions of hundreds of cardboard boxes:

```
df = [[17829292, (13, 14, 20)], [17739292, (20, 10, 15)], [17827792, (10, 10, 12)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Serial Number', 'Box Dimensions'])
```

Given that the 'Box Dimensions' column contains a list of numbers, is there a simple way to search through the dataframe for all boxes with dimensions less than or equal to certain values, <= (15, 15, 15)? Or do I need to separate out each box's (x, y, z) values into three separate columns to evaluate them this way?

I've tried `df.loc[df['Box Dimensions'] <= (15, 15, 15)]`, but for some reason this only evaluates the first number in the list. The function will return boxes whose x values are <=15, but whose y and z dimensions exceed these parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
m=pd.DataFrame(df['Box Dimensions'].tolist()).le(15).all(1)
#OR(If needed to check dimensions seperately above method can be modified as well)
m=df['Box Dimensions'].map(lambda x:x[0]<=15 and x[1]<=15 and x[2]<=15)
#Finally:
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
```

output of above code:

```
    Serial Number   Box Dimensions
2   17827792        (10, 10, 12)
```

Comment: Thank you! So it seems buried in the code you provided it IS necessary to split the list values into three separate columns.

Comment: @Mariah_5288 not necessarly...it's upto you can make Dataframe out of `df['Box Dimensions']` values and then check or use `map()` for checking the value inside the tuple of values inside `df['Box Dimensions']` or you can use the `str` accessor as mentioned in the other answer...and yes you need to check every element of tuple

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you need to test box dimensions independently

```
 df.loc[(df['Box Dimensions'].str[0] <= 15) & (df['Box Dimensions'].str[1] <= 15) & (df['Box Dimensions'].str[2] <= 15)]


   Serial Number Box Dimensions
2       17827792   (10, 10, 12)
```